# template naming for precompile

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using Grunt and Yeoman to precompile my handlebars templates for an ember app.

In the tutorial they write:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
...
</script>
```

Instead I have a file `todos.hbs`

Now I have to create a template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos/index">
</script>
```

What syntax do I use to make a `todos/index` `.hbs` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new folder `todos` in the template directory and create an `index.hbs` file in it.

Comment: ok cool. I was a little worried about new directories messing Grunt up but see that they will still be compiled. In `Gruntfile.js`: `emberTemplates: {
                files: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.hbs',`

Answer (score 1):

Is your `todos/index` a nested ressource?

With Grunt in this case, I put my `todos.hbs` in the parent folder of the nested ressource, render only the `{{outlet}}`-tag in it and put `todos/index` named as `index.hbs` in a subfolder called `todos`. Inside these templates, i usually omit the `<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos/index">...</script>` part, because Grunt recognizes them based on their filename.

If your routes are not nested, you should be able to do the same without the subfolders. Correct me if I'm wrong

Be sure to configure your Grunt to watch subfolders for changes when doing it that way. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104727/how-to-make-grunt-watch-subfolder-for-handlebars-templates-ember-js-app-with-ye)
I hope this helps

Comment: See @kingpin2k 's short answer ;)